# Acronym option for accsupp package: (how) does this work?

Tags: acronyms

I'm trying to use the `E` acronym feature option from the `accsupp` package. It is actually not really documented what it should do, but I would like to obtain something like the HTML `title` tag in images, related question: [How can I get pdflatex to make tooltips attached to text, like HTML's abbr tag?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5674)

The MWE below works as advertized if I replace `E` by `ActualText`, but with the option `E` it doesn't show anything special, nor does it give an alternate text on copy&paste. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a non-implemented feature. I'm using Adobe reader version 9.3.2 under Linux.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand{\acronym}[2]{%
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,E=#2}%
#1%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}

Test: \acronym{USA}{United States of America}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I understand it this property is not for copying text from the PDF but to have it read by a creen reader, see for example [Providing definitions for abbreviations via an E entry for a structure element](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/PDF8.html) or the [PDF reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference.pdf)