# Tooltip that works with all pdf readers

Tags: pdfcomment, fancytooltips, tooltips

Is it possible to get tooltips into a LaTeX pdf?

I am working on my CV. I would like to show some more information on my electronic version once you swipe over that field with the mouse. i.e. when swiping with the mouse over education I want to show my subjects taken in undergrad through a tooltip.

Is this possible and if yes would if work for all kind of pdf readers?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Would it work for all kinds of PDF readers? Maybe not.

Comment: How PDF viewers show 'hover text' is down the them, not the source (LaTeX or otherwise). Thus the best you can hope is to check with a set of viewers.

Comment: You have alreay tagged with an according package name, cf. also [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82336). There is at least the package `pdfcomments`, as well. For the PDF readers: As example SumatraPDF does not at all execute such tooltips.

Comment: Also interesting: [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356). Quite probably there are more of this.

Comment: @Speravir SumatraPDF does now work well with `pdfcomments`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Finally I came up with a `\tooltip` command that works across a small number of **PDF viewers**, among which is an **Open-Source** one. The tooltip command allows for TeX-formatted tip texts.

> ```
> \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
>            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
>            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
>            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
> ```

It comes in **five** variants:

```
%draggable tip box (e. g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108998),
%visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
\tooltip{<link text>}{<tip text>}

%draggable tip box, toggle visibility on mouse-over (a second wipe hides the tip)
\tooltip*{<link text>}{<tip text>}  

%NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
\tooltip**{<link text>}{<tip text>}  

%NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
\tooltip***{<link text>}{<tip text>}

%NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click
\tooltip****{<link text>}{<tip text>}
```

For **Evince** (open-source), only the command with 4 stars `\tooltip****` is usable, because **mouse-click** is the only event Evince listens for. In **Acrobat Reader**, all variants are functional.

The non-draggable variants (two and more stars) do *not* use any JavaScript.

If `hyperref` is loaded, the colour of internal links (`hyperref` option `linkcolor`) is used as `<link colour>`.

---

In order to break longer `<tip text>` into multiple lines, wrap it in a `\parbox` of given width:

```
\tootltip{link text}{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{... long tip text ...}}
```

---

**Evince:**

[image]

**A-Reader:**

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper,12pt]{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2019/09/26
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
%            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
%            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,linegoal}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\cListSet\clist_set:Nn\let\cListItem\clist_item:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}mO{0pt,0pt}%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    %\fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \tcbox[colframe=black,colback=#7,size=fbox,arc=1ex,sharp corners=southwest]{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \cListSet\tpOffsets{#9}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tipshift=0pt%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    %OCG-based (that is, all non-draggable) boxes should not extend beyond the
    %current column as they may get overlaid by text in the neighbouring column
    \setlength\whatsleft{\linegoal}%
  }{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  }%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\dimexpr\twd+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax%
    \setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd-\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp+\cListItem\tpOffsets{2}}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\dimexpr\tipshift+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
  Einstein's \tooltip****{formula}{$E=m c^2$} is well known.
  Another famous formula is due to \tooltip****{Pythagoras}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}.

  This \tooltip{tip}{is visible only in AR} is draggable and shown on mouse-over.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What package/class provides `\ocgbase@new@ocg`?

Comment: @1010011010 `ocgbase.sty` (part of package `ocgx2`) loaded by `media9.sty`.

Comment: I copy/pasted the code above but the compilation failed.
Does someone has an idea why? The complete log file is [there](http://pastebin.com/SKZCRCVw).
The first error message is: 
`! Undefined control sequence.
\tpPdfXform ->\pbs_pdfxform:nnn 
                                {1}{1}
l.133   Einstein's \tooltip**{formula}{$E=m c^2$}
                                                  is well known.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. [...]`

Comment: The problem seems to be that my system is too old. see: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32189614#32189614

Comment: I could not make this solution to work. It complained that tooltip was not recognized. Anyway, I swiched to [pdfcomment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17004/25124)

Comment: @MikaëlMayer : What did complain? `pdflatex`? Your PDF viewer? Maybe your TeX installation needs an upgrade (I recommend TeXLive-2017). I compiled the code with `pdflatex` (TL 2017) and opened the PDF in Evince. The links "formula" and "Pythagoras" work as advertised.

Comment: I found why it did not work. I received no complaint from a spelling error in the name of the file containing your macro. Now it is fixed. Thanks !

Comment: It will not work if I put two or more asterisks. It says \tpPdfLink has an extra }, paragraph ended before \tpPdfLink was complete and a bunch of undefined control sequences for \ocgbase. =(
(I'm using texlive-full package on Debian 9 'Stretch')

Comment: "TeXLive" means nothing. Which version do you use? Look at the top of the *.log file.

Comment: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.3.3)". Is this too old? =/

Comment: TL-16 is definitely too old. TL-17 is final now and TL-18 to be released end of april.

Comment: Very good! But I get: "Package typearea Warning: Maybe no optimal type area setting"

Comment: The example makes use of A6 papersize (post card) and a `\Huge` font just for the sake of producing the nice screen recording shown above, but which is not optimal in terms of typography (as juged by the `scrbook` documentclass used here). For real-world applications, other papersize/font combinations would be used and the warning would disappear. Since It is unrelated to the `\tooltip` macro you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: I copy pasted this into an [overleaf document](https://www.overleaf.com/1359873772yfkzwqtjdwcm) but the it doesn't compile properly. The editor doesn't seem to know ```\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}``` and ```\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull```

Comment: Overleaf's package status is ancient. You would be better off having TeXLive or MiKTeX installed on your computer.

Comment: Small issue with `\tooltip****`: Firefox's built-in PDF viewer (pdfjs) shows the tooltip boxes unconditionally (even if you don't click anything).

Comment: @copy It's Firefox's fault.

Comment: Would I be correct to think that it won't work on a cellphone (since ocg is use and ocg are not working on cellphone, to my knowledge)? I obviously don't own a cellphone or tablet to try it.

Comment: This is most likely correct. On portable devices it wouldn't work.

Comment: These don't work in preview on mac or in Google Chrome.

Comment: They don't, indeed. Send a feature request to Google, asking for OCG, Forms and JavaScript support in their PDF viewer.

Answer (score 6):

Tooltips in PDF documents are generally possible. I do know two packages; one of them you tagged yourself for your question, the other one I added, click on these tags to see, which questions were already asked in TeX.SX: [fancytooltips](/questions/tagged/fancytooltips) & [pdfcomment](/questions/tagged/pdfcomment). But as Joseph Wright in a comment wrote:

> How PDF viewers show 'hover text' is down the them, not the source (LaTeX or otherwise). Thus the best you can hope is to check with a set of viewers.

I can tell you, that SumatraPDF, a popular viewer for Windows, does not show any tooltip at all with “tooltip” in a strict meaning, but does show comments, when you hover with the mouse over one of them. What is supported, what not, can be seen when reading the documentation of package [`pdfcomment`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfcomment). There is a type `\pdfmarkupcomment` that actually almost acts like a tooltip.

See also this fixed bug in SumatraPDF Bug tracker: [PDF Comments Don't Work](https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=1312&can=1&q=tooltip).

Comment: correction: Tooltips in PDF documents are generally impossible :)

Comment: The rest of the answer explains why.

Comment: That's also my conclusion from the last 15 minutes of research and trying to get one of the solutions to work. I think they're all pdf-viewer-specific. Preview on Mac and Google Chrome won't display things correctly. It's not really satisfactory to have a solution that only works on a few PDF viewers.