# Making drop down lists in PDF

Tags: math-mode, ocg

I want to write some notes with a bunch of lengthy derivations. Is there a possibility to hide the derivation in the pdf to ensure readability, but show it (i.e. via some drop down) on demand - i.e. by clicking some button?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps, something like [↗Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186)

Comment: You could also hypelink to the proof in an appendix, or even a separate file using `\href[pdfnewwindow]`

Comment: @John : ... which is, without any doubt, the most robust option and to be preferred for non-presentation type documents.