# How to include an image in the second argument of /tooltip?

Tags: graphics, tooltips

How to use /tooltip can be read here: [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers/164186#164186)

The question is: can you insert an image into the second argument of such a tooltip?

I have failed to do so. Instead, the image just shows up and the tooltip functionality is lost.

Comment: What do you mean with 'the tooltip functionality is lost' after the image showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a graphic as a tooltip. The number of PDF viewers that can be used is limited, though. The second tooltip opens on click and also works in Evince:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2017/11/28
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]][<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%               
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%              
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}m%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%  
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%  
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\Huge
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is a \tooltip{tooltip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}} with a graphic popping up on mouse-over in Acrobat Reader. The tooltip can be dragged around with the mouse.
  \item This is a \tooltip****{tooltip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}} with a graphic popping up on mouse-click. Besides Acrobat Reader, this works also in Evince.
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer solved the problem. Do you see any possibility of slightly changing the position (offset) of an image?

Comment: It's the line starting with `\raisebox...` where you may insert additional vertical and horizontal space. The current default is to align the lower left corner of the tip box with the upper right corner of the link.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand how for example  `\raisebox{\heightof{#4}+\tdp-200px}` will lower the Tooltip by 200 pixels. But I have [a different follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391924/how-to-change-the-position-of-a-image-tooltip-to-the-utmost-or-almost-left) now, which asks for re-positioning the Tooltip relative to the utmost left-corner of the page. Could you please help me with this question?