# How to change the position of a (image) /tooltip to the utmost (or almost) left corner of the page?

Tags: graphics, tooltips

Following [AlexG's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391517/67761) to the question [How to include an image in the second argument of /tooltip?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391512/how-to-include-an-image-in-the-second-argument-of-tooltip) I would like to ask how it is possible to change the position of the tooltip so that the image (or tooltip in general) will always be positioned with its top-left corner starting at the complete (or almost complete) top-left of the page.

In other words, how to make the position of the tooltip (or rather the position of its second argument) relative to the page, not to the position of the contents of its first argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example places pop-up boxes with embedded graphic files at the top-left page corner. The `tikzpicture` environment with options "`rememberpicture, overlay`" is used for absolute positioning.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX
%
% optimized for Adobe Reader (visible on mouse-over)
%     usage: \tooltip[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%   non-draggable version:
%     usage: \tooltip*[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
% for Evince (visible on click, not draggable)
%   usage: \tooltip**[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{ssO{blue}mO{yellow!20}m}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border [0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
          /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
        >>%
      }{
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
              if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                var click\thetcnt=false;%
                var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
              }%
            }%
            if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
              fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
            }%
           this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
            if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
            this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
          /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
            fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
        >>%
      }
    }%
  }{{\color{#3}#4}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox{black}{#5}{#6}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  %tip box placed at top left page corner
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=base] at (current page.north west) {%
      \raisebox{-\tht}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
          /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
          /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
          /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
          \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
            /Ff 65537/OC \tpTipOcg%
          }{%
            /Ff 65536/F 3%
            /AA <<%
              /U <<%
                /S/JavaScript/JS(%
                  var fd=event.target;%
                  var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
                  var drag=function(){%
                    var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                    var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                    var fdr=fd.rect;%
                    fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                    fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
                  };%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                    dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
                  }%
                  else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
                  this.dirty=false;%
                )%
              >>%
            >>%
          }%
        }%
        \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
      }%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\Huge
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is a \tooltip{tooltip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}} with a graphic popping up on mouse-over in Acrobat Reader. The tooltip can be dragged around with the mouse.
  \item This is a \tooltip**{tooltip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}} with a graphic popping up on mouse-click. Besides Acrobat Reader, this works also in Evince.
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's really awesome @AlexG You are the god.

Comment: The annoying thing is that, now (because of all of the images are to be placed on top or below one another) one has to close all the images on top to see the image you would like to see under them ... It would be nice if this could be adapted so that only one image can be shown at a time. Perhaps another question ...? :)

Comment: Use the single starred variant `\tooltip*{link text}{tip text/image}. The tip  is visible only as long as the mouse is over the link text and disappears as soon as you leave it for another one. But this is Acrobat Reader only.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the extremely quick fix!