# How to start with a, b, c,... and end up with 1a2a3, 1b2b3, 1c2c3,

Tags: graphics, l3regex, tooltips

So imagine you have a certain code which looks like this:

```
ABC, some text , LaLaLa
\tooltip*{A}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{images/A}}\tooltip*{B}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{images/B}}\tooltip*{C}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{images/C}}
```

Now note that the contents of the first {*argument*} of `\tooltip` re-appears in the {*argument*} of `\includegraphics`.

Now, in this case I manually input the **A** and **B** and **C** of the `\includegraphics`, to match with the **A** and **B** and **C** of `\tooltip`. But what if we would like to find a way for Tex to do this automatically?

Or even better, what if you would like to find a way to create an environment in which the end-user only has to type:

```
ABC
```

to automatically reproduce the first code?

I guess this could be done using *regex*, so how could you do it in a LaTeX way?

---

**==DEFINITIONS==**

What is meant by Tooltip here, can be found explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers/164186#164186).

Comment: What do you mean by the "first code"?   Just the three`\tooltip` lines?

Comment: Why a regex? If you are okay with the input form `A,B,C,D` use a comma-separated list (l3clist) and just use a map function to give you tooltip and image...

Comment: But please post a full minimal working example (MWE), which is compilable.

Comment: @TeXnician Actually I am not OK with a comma-seperated list. I would like the symbols to be right next to each-other, as such: `ABCD`

Comment: Is there only one letter per tooltip? Then you can do this also in a very simple way.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, indeed. Only one letter per tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of what you're trying to do, but here's a fairly general approach, based on the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/4427

This doesn't support `\tooltips**`, but it would be easy to extend it.

The first optional argument is for `\includegraphics` options to be passed to every picture; the trailing optional argument is for setting a separation between the items (default nothing).

```
\documentclass[a6paper,12pt]{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX
%
% optimized for Adobe Reader (visible on mouse-over)
%     usage: \tooltip[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%   non-draggable version:
%     usage: \tooltip*[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
% for Evince (visible on click, not draggable)
%   usage: \tooltip**[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{ssO{blue}mO{yellow!20}m}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border [0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
          /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
        >>%
      }{
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
              if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                var click\thetcnt=false;%
                var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
              }%
            }%
            if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
              fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
            }%
           this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
            if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
            this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
          /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
            fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
        >>%
      }
    }%
  }{{\color{#3}#4}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox{black}{#5}{#6}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#4}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
      /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
      /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        /Ff 65537/OC \tpTipOcg%
      }{%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
    }%
    \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltips}{sO{}m+O{}}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tooltip*}{\tooltip}{##1}{\includegraphics[#2]{##1}}#4
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tooltips[width=2cm]{example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}

\bigskip

\tooltips[width=2cm]{example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}[\par]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow @egreg thank you. I am very happy that the interactivity of the `\tooltip` has been preserved now. There is a problem though. Your code works if I put an images **A.png** and **B.png** next to your **.tex** file, and I change your code to `\tooltips[scale=1]{A,B}`. But what I would actually like it to do is to work for such images without the comma. Just like  `\tooltips[scale=1]{ABCD}` and so on. Do you think your answer could be adapted to achieve this?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen Yes, of course: change `\clist_map_inline:nn` into `\tl_map_inline:nn`. That's one thing I was unsure of: it greatly limits the possibility of naming the images.

Comment: Building on your code I have [one final question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392227/either-batch-transcode-character-sets-a-whole-list-of-image-filenames-or-u) to ask before  my purpose is reached. It's about what to do when the whole image-set using a different encoding. Batch convert either the image filenames (and how?) or use a conversion function within your code?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I don't understand; what encoding are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used the word encoding. It's all in the new (now already solved) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392227/either-batch-transcode-character-sets-a-whole-list-of-image-filenames-or-u).

Comment: How could I stop the code from jamming if one character doesn't have a corresponding image please?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies, I shouldn't have used the word *character* above, as it does not suit the generic case. Currently, if one includes `\tooltips[width=2cm]{example-image-abc}` there will be an error `File 'example-image-abc' not found`. My question is: how to prevent this error from popping up, and just let the document proceed with compiling instead.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I still don't understand: what are you planning to do for missing images? If you type a wrong name, LaTeX warns you, what else?

Comment: The problem is that I am using this code on a (traditional Chinese) text, which will look for each (traditional Chinese) character's stroke order image (meaning perhaps tens of thousands of characters, and thousands of images). The problem is that my set of images is not complete. Meaning there might be a hundred of such errors, which might be a nuisance. I know one could ignore all errors, but that would still require some sort of user-interaction during compilation on the system I am on (TeXShop).

Comment: The problem with skipping all errors at once (which is possible in TeXShop) is that I **only** want the image-errors of the type `File '...` not found. If I would skip all compilation-errors for the whole document (perhaps also ones not of the type above), I might thus miss other errors I do want to get notified of.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I seem to remember that this problem has already been discussed. Please, do a search and, if you find nothing, ask a new question.

Comment: I have asked [a new question about the error-message filtering using the package **silence**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394494/package-silence-what-i-am-misunderstanding-about-filtering-out-error-messages) just now.

Comment: I still very much enjoy your code, but have found there is some sort of incompatibility with including `\kern` into it (well I also combined it with a separator). I have therefor asked a new OP at "[Why is there a conflict between \kern and this customized Tooltips/Separator command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395793/why-is-there-a-conflict-between-kern-and-this-customized-tooltips-command)".

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? You certainly don't need a regex to do this. Here's a solution using `etoolbox`'s `\docsvlist`. I've given a simple definition of `\tooltip`, since you don't define it, and I assume it's not directly relevant for the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\tooltip}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\ttips}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\do[1]{\tooltip{##1}\includegraphics[width=1cm]{images/##1}}
  \docsvlist{#1}}
\begin{document}
\ttips{A,B,C}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @Ala_Munn Let me specify what is meant by Tooltip in the OP. My apologies.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen It's unlikely that the actual definition matters. If this syntax for the `\ttips` macro is useful to you then you can supply your own version of `\tooltip`.

Comment: @Alan_Munn I see what you mean, but people who don't know what they are doing (like me) might get errors such as: `Command \tooltip already defined.`

Comment: @VincentVerheyen that's why questions should _always_  (well almost always) have a complete test file supplied!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hear you. I hope you like [my follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392227/either-batch-transcode-character-sets-a-whole-list-of-image-filenames-or-u), which now shows the complete test file and use-case.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX has a suitable loop already defined so you just need

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\tooltip#1{[ttip-#1]}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{%
 \@tfor\tmp:=#1\do{%
 \tooltip{\tmp}%
 \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-\tmp}%
 }}

\begin{document}

\zz{abc}

\end{document}
```

adjust the definition of `\tooltip` as required.

Answer (score 1):

With the `listofitems` package.  The list delimiter (default `,`) can be reset with `\setsepchar{<delimiter>}`.  Reset `\tooltip` as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,graphicx}
\def\tooltip#1{[ttip-#1]}
\newcommand\retool[1]{%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{%
    \tooltip{\i}%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-\i}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\retool{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To use a list with no delimiters, here is an adaptation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,graphicx}
\def\tooltip#1{[ttip-#1]}
\newcommand\retool[1]{%
  \def\tmp{}%
  \ignoreemptyitems%
  \pretool#1\relax%
  \readlist*\mylist{\tmp}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{%
    \tooltip{\i}%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-\i}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\pretool#1#2\relax{%
  \g@addto@macro\tmp{#1,}%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\pretool#2\relax\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\retool{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if we would want no delimiter please, but instead have an image for every single character?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen The one disallowed case, unfortunately...but I will adapt something.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I have revised my answer to provide an adaptation that uses each token of the argument as input.