# Package silence - What I am misunderstanding about filtering out error messages based on their output?

Tags: errors, silence

So here's an excerpt from the package called **silence**:

> These are the same as the starless versions above, except that they
>   target the message not as it appears in the log file but as it was
>   produced. For instance, suppose you have an undefined citation, that
>   is you wrote \cite{Spinoza1677} and LATEX complains as follows:
>
> `LaTeX Warning: Citation ‘Spinoza1677’ on page 4 undefined on input
>   line 320.`
>
> You know you have to bring your bibliography up to date, but right now
>   you’re working on a terrific idea and you don’t have time to waste. So
>   you say:
>
> `\WarningFilter{latex}{Citation ‘Spinoza1677’}`

I myself am compiling using **LuaLaTeX** and have a lot of errors of the following type:

`LaTeX Error: File 'files/images/`...`' not found.`

With some more specific stuff where the three dots are located.

I am trying to filter these error mesesages out. But using:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{File}
```

or

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{File 'files/images}
```

somehow isn't working.

Comment: your snippets show you used a WarningFilter but had an Error, Warnings are not the same as errors.

Comment: Why not use the demo option?

Comment: @Johannes_B Could you elaborate a bit on your suggestion please?

Comment: Add `demo` to your global options.

Answer (score 1):

As per User David Carlisle's comment (first comment to OP), the trick was to change

`\WarningFilter{latex}`

into

`\ErrorFilter{latex}`.