# \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec} - What's so special about ﹑and ～ (OP2)

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec, luatexja

In my previous OP entitled "[What's so special about ﹑and ～](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394524/whats-so-special-about-and-%EF%BD%9E)", we have discovered [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394619/67761) to make that question's MWE compile, by changing

```
\begin{document}
```

into

```
\begin{document} \catcode`\﹑=12 \catcode`\～=12
```

However, while I was trying out somebody else's code, I came up with a new **MWE** (hence a new OP) in which the solution above doesn't work any longer. In the mean-time I have also found out that the culprit is `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}`.

Indeed, the **MWE** below is a neat separator code, which can separate the text in betwen `\maincommand{`...`}` and apply commands to each character of the included text, while applying other commands to the punctuation marks themselves (`\punctdef`). This works for countless of punctuation marks I have tried. ***It works with or without*** loading the package `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}`.

***With one exception***: it seems one can not have both:

- `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}`

as well as one (or both) of the following:

- `\punctdef～{～}`
- `\punctdef﹑{﹑}`

My question is: how to solve this incompatibility between the package `luatexja-fontspec` and the commands issued for `～` and `﹑`?

Please note one can uncomment `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}` in the **MWE** below to see the problems.

Changing

```
\begin{document}
```

into

```
\begin{document} \catcode`\﹑=12 \catcode`\～=12
```

doesn't help in this case.

## MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For luatexja-fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec} % IF YOU UNCOMMENT \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}, THIS CODE WILL FAIL, UNLESS YOU REPLACE ALL INSTANCES OF ～ AND ALL INSTANCES OF ﹑ BY SOME OTHER PUNCTUATION MARK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Separator (\maincommand)
\def\chinchar#1{[#1]} % redefine it if you want...
\def\punctdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname p-#1\endcsname}

\def\maincommand#1{\maincommandA#1\relax}
\def\maincommandA#1{\ifx\relax#1\else
      \expandafter\ifx\csname p-#1\endcsname\relax \chinchar{#1}%
      \else \csname p-#1\endcsname\fi
   \expandafter\maincommandA\fi
}
%
\punctdef～{～\kern1em}
\punctdef﹑{﹑\kern1em}
\punctdef,{,\kern1em}
\punctdef:{:\kern1em}
\punctdef;{;\kern13pt}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document} \catcode`\﹑=12 \catcode`\～=12

\maincommand{AB～C,,,DE;FG:H}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't prefix `#1` by `\string`. Please, read my previous code carefully.

Comment: Why didn't you use `\string` prefix as mentioned in my code here?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395793/

Comment: @wipet I made this MWE while implementing [the first revision of your code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/395912/1), where no `\string` was present yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ～ character is set with catcode 11 (letter) when `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}` is used. So the `\punctdef～` is interpreted as one control sequnce, of course undefined  cotnrol sequence. It is clear from the error report:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \punctdef～
```

The solution is simple. Use `\punctdef{～}{...}` instead `\punctdef～{...}` in such cases. Moreover, the `\catcode` settings immediately after `\begin{document}` is totally irrelevant. Remove it.

**Edit** I add another information here in order to stop creating of next and next new questions.

The `﹑` character has another problem. When you use it then it is not printed. You can see the message in log file:

```
Missing character: There is no ﹑ (U+FE51) in font IPAExMincho:jfm=ujis!
```

But you can use `\punctdef` to define another way for printing of such character. For example:

```
\punctdef{﹑}{\leavevmode\lower1ex\hbox{\tt`}\kern1em}
```