# How can I change the shape of Tooltip box?

Tags: pdfcomment, fancytooltips, tooltips

I am using the easiest way of `tooltip` code that posted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/108724) by @AlexG. it works very well but in long tooltips, it doesn't break the lines in output (as shown in the following screen shot)

[image]

> **Q1:** How can I use this `tooltip` with fixed width?
>
> **Q2:** How can I change the shape of this `tooltip` box? e.g. a hurt shape or circle instead of rectangle. (at least rounded corner rectangle.)

Comment: For Q1, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396732 .

Comment: Q2: In the `\tooltip` code, replace `\fcolorbox` with something fancier, maybe from package `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions have been incorporated in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For multiline text, wrap the tip text into a `\parbox` of given width:

```latex
   \tooltip****{foo}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{... long text ...}}
```

2. For rounded corners, replace `\fcolorbox` in the tooltip code with, e. g., `\tcbox` from package `tcolorbox`

```latex
   %\fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
   \tcbox[colframe=black,colback=#7,size=fbox,arc=1ex]{#8}%
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2019/09/26
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
%            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
%            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,linegoal}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\cListSet\clist_set:Nn\let\cListItem\clist_item:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}mO{0pt,0pt}%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    %\fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \tcbox[colframe=black,colback=#7,size=fbox,arc=1ex,sharp corners=southwest]{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \cListSet\tpOffsets{#9}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tipshift=0pt%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    %OCG-based (that is, all non-draggable) boxes should not extend beyond the
    %current column as they may get overlaid by text in the neighbouring column
    \setlength\whatsleft{\linegoal}%
  }{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  }%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\dimexpr\twd+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax%
    \setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd-\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp+\cListItem\tpOffsets{2}}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\dimexpr\tipshift+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tooltip****{foo}{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{Some longer text wrapped in a {\ttfamily \string\parbox} such that it breaks into several lines.}}
and also \tooltip****{bar}{\parbox{0.2\linewidth}{\begin{displaymath}\int_0^1 2x dx = 1\end{displaymath}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome reply...

Comment: ...and awesome animation :-)

Comment: ++1, I have nothing to say.

Comment: @C.F.G Thank you! By chance, do you use it in a right-to-left writing context? I would like to know whether it is usable there too. I only tested with English text.

Comment: @AlexG: Ohh, I don't know why I didn't see your comment!!! I am so sorry. Yes, I am using  right-to-left writing context (by XeLaTeX).

Comment: @AlexG: I am using `xepersian` package where your  code produce the following error: `LaTeX3 Error: '\box_use_clear:N' deprecated on 2019-01-01. Use(LaTeX3) with the option 'undo-recent-deprecations'. \end{document}`

Comment: @AlexG: I have a problem. Why this not working?: `\tooltip{my Theorem}{\ref{thm:2}}`?

Comment: @C.F.G Clickable references in the tooltip box are possible only with the NON-draggable tooltip variants (`\tooltip` command with 2 and more `*`). This is due to a limitation of the PDF file format. But you can disable hyperlinks inside the box: `\tooltip{my Theorem}{\begin{NoHyper}\ref{thm:2}\end{NoHyper}}`

Comment: `\tooltip{my Theorem}{\begin{NoHyper}\ref{thm:2}\end{NoHyper}}` not working. I think it needs something like `\expandafter` maybe.

Comment: @C.F.G Did you load `hyperref`? I tried with `\eqref` which worked.

Comment: @AlexG: You are right. I am using `\ref{}` inside `\begin{theorem} \end{theorem}` .i.e. \tooltip****{Theorem}{\begin{theorem}\ref{thm:2} \end{theorem}}` that the `\tooltip` has some problem with `theorem` env.

Comment: @AlexG: But now works only with `\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{}`. Thanks.