# Interactive SVG

Tags: graphics, svg, interaction

I would like to be able to click inside a (white) box in an image like:
[image]
and then jump to the description of that function.
I tried:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  unicode%
}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false,
             bookmarksnumbered=true,
             pdfencoding=unicode
            }

\section{\texorpdfstring{fie1()}{fie1()}}

References \mbox{\hyperlink{aa_8h_af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2}{fie2}} ().

Here is the call graph for this function:
\nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{aa_8h_a321294a1af6610f2dc1563ebee9cdfbe_cgraph}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\section{\texorpdfstring{fie2()}{fie2()}}

\end{document}
```

with the include image based on (the `.dot` file):

```
digraph "fie1"
{
 // INTERACTIVE_SVG=YES
  edge [fontname="Helvetica",fontsize="10",labelfontname="Helvetica",labelfontsize="10"];
  node [fontname="Helvetica",fontsize="10",shape=record];
  rankdir="LR";
  Node0 [label="fie1",height=0.2,width=0.4,color="black", fillcolor="grey75", style="filled", fontcolor="black"];
  Node0 -> Node1 [color="midnightblue",fontsize="10",style="solid"];
  Node1 [label="fie2",height=0.2,width=0.4,color="black", fillcolor="white", style="filled",URL="$aa_8h.html#af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2"];
}
```

but this leads not to a clickable situation.
I also tried with svg (after installing Inkscape):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  unicode%
}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false,
             bookmarksnumbered=true,
             pdfencoding=unicode
            }

\section{\texorpdfstring{fie1()}{fie1()}}

References \mbox{\hyperlink{aa_8h_af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2}{fie2}} ().

Here is the call graph for this function:
\nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includesvg{aa_8h_a321294a1af6610f2dc1563ebee9cdfbe_cgraph}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\section{\texorpdfstring{fie2()}{fie2()}}

\end{document}
```

with the necessary SVG file being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: fie1 Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="108pt" height="28pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 108.00 28.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 24)">
<title>fie1</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-24 104,-24 104,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- Node0 -->
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>Node0</title>
<polygon fill="#bfbfbf" stroke="black" points="0,-0.5 0,-19.5 32,-19.5 32,-0.5 0,-0.5"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="16" y="-7.5" font-family="Helvetica,sans-Serif" font-size="10.00">fie1</text>
</g>
<!-- Node1 -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>Node1</title>
<g id="a_node2"><a xlink:href="aa_8h.html#af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2" target="_top" xlink:title="fie2">
<polygon fill="white" stroke="black" points="68,-0.5 68,-19.5 100,-19.5 100,-0.5 68,-0.5"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="84" y="-7.5" font-family="Helvetica,sans-Serif" font-size="10.00">fie2</text>
</a>
</g>
</g>
<!-- Node0&#45;&gt;Node1 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>Node0&#45;&gt;Node1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="midnightblue" d="M32.3076,-10C39.8047,-10 49.0314,-10 57.5491,-10"/>
<polygon fill="midnightblue" stroke="midnightblue" points="57.7754,-13.5001 67.7754,-10 57.7754,-6.5001 57.7754,-13.5001"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

but unfortunately also without result.

There is a restriction that the image cannot be draw by hand as it is automatically generated and a document can have quite a few of these type of images that also change when the underlying code changes. It is, probably, possible to modify the generating code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you generate TikZ and not SVG?

Comment: Probably I can generate TikZ, but I have no experience with TikZ (but I can and I'm willing to learn it). The given picture is quite easy, but normally the pictures contain (many) more nodes and dot nicely arranges these, I don't know if this is automatically possible with TikZ. Any hints in this direction are very welcome.

Comment: Well, if you _generate_ TikZ, you don't need to know it. And the final assembly is easy, since TikZ is LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. Just for my knowledge would it be possible to create something like the .dot file? Or how would the TikZ file / part look like analogous to the above .dot file (so I have a nice jump start)?

Comment: I don't really get it with .dot file and have troubles directly converting you SVG to TikZ with https://github.com/paaguti/svg2tikz.

Comment: But basically you just `\input` the generated TikZ. As it's all LaTeX, you can also set is as link anchor for `hyperref`.

Comment: Sorry, I do understand your point regarding the unknown `.dot` file, made a small update of the question. I'll have a look at the svg2tikz package.

Comment: I also have problems with svg2tikz ( :-( ). I also tried dot2tex but here I get a tex / tikz file but the boxes and background are missing.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with pdf layers named `ocg` (Optional Content Groups). These are layers of the pdf file that can be displayed or hidden by a simple mouse click. Not all pdf readers support them, I know that `Adobe reader`, `Evince` or `Foxit reader` manage these `ocg` layers.

There are several packages that allow to use them: `ocg`, `ocg-p`, `ocgtools`, `ocgx` and `ocgx2`.

The most complete manual and examples are the `ocgx` package available here: [ocgx-manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx)
A beautiful demo of `ocgx` package is here: [demo-ocgx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf)

I didn't quite understand your request and maybe I didn't do what you wanted.

In the following code, clicking on the rectangle `fie2` changes the display of the rectangle `fie1` and displays the word `definition`.
It is of course possible to do it differently, to display or not the arrow, etc..

I used `tikz` to draw and display rectangles, but you can also hide and display something else like **text** or an **image**.

In the following code, `node (a)` is a rectangle that displays the default word `fie1`. `Node (b)` is a `fie2` rectangle containing a link that makes visible the layer I called `fie1` displaying the word `definition`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) [draw,very thick,rounded corners=1pt,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm] {fie1};   
\node (b) at (4,0) [draw,very thick,rounded corners=1pt,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,switch ocg=fie1] {fie2};   
\path[->](a) edge [very thick,blue](b);

\begin{scope}[ocg={name=fie1,ref=fie1,status=invisible}]
\node (a) at (0,0) [draw,very thick,rounded corners=1pt,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,fill=white] {definition};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On the image below, the `ocg` layer `fie1` is **inactive** and the message displayed is the default `fie1`.

[image: inactive-ocg]

On the image below, the `ocg` layer `fie1` has been **activated** by clicking `fie2` and now displays the word `definition`.

[image: active-ocg]

If I didn't understand your request correctly, say so.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: The idea is that when clicking on `fie2` one jumps to another part in the pdf file /  documentation where the function is described.

Comment: @albert Is this part on the same page or on another page of the pdf?

Comment: Both are possible, but I have an hypertarget (in the original SVG shown as: `xlink:href="aa_8h.html#af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2` for the LaTex document this target would be `af60813d22831048d88007bf793ba9df2`, I can influence this).

Comment: @albert If the definition is on the same page, it is possible to display a tooltip with the packages `fancytooltips`, `cooltooltips` and maybe (I'm not sure of that) `pdfcomment`

Comment: OK I will have to study those packages.

Comment: @albert Also study this answer which uses the `pdfcomment` package https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/138900