# Making accessible graphs in LaTex

Tags: accessibility

Does anyone know how to make a tagged document with graphs in LaTex? I tried adding a comment and a label to a graph, but the .pdf file still fails (missing alternate text) through Adobe's Full Check. I also use Adobe Autotag before Full Check. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in, bottom=1.1in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{img}
\label{fig:img.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, your document does not seem to be compilable. Apart from the fact that it includes a graphics that probably not too many of us have, it uses the `\pdftooltip` command without loading appropriate packages that define it. BTW, I'd also like to draw your attention to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/121799).

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the \pdftooltip command...

Comment: For tagged PDFs have a look at the experimental tagpdf package.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add the alt text with acrobat. But beside this you can use the accsupp package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{Alt={my figure},method=escape}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:img.jpg}
\EndAccSupp{}
\end{document}
```

Something similar can be done with the tagpdf package mentioned in the comments:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{uncompress, %for the test, to check the pdf
             activate-mc}
\begin{document}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Figure,alttext={my figure}}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:img.jpg}
\tagmcend
\end{document}
```

#### But attention

- tagpdf is an experimental package!
- unlike accsupp tagpdf hasn't currently different input methods for the alttext key. Its value is handled as verbatim, no TeX commands are expanded.

Comment: If I tried your suggestion, then I got the error  `Package tagpdf Error: PDF resource management is no active!
(tagpdf)                tagpdf will no work..` Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi as the documentation says tagpdf now requires the pdfmanagement. Put `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} \DocumentMetadata{}` before \documentclass.

Comment: My tags are follows: `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} \DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{uncompress, %for the test, to check the pdf
             activate-mc}
\begin{document}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Figure,alttext={my figure}}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:img.jpg}
\tagmcend
\end{document}` but still I got the error `Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DocumentMetadata` Please advise...

Comment: I'm using `XeLaTeX` in `MikTeX V2.9` in `Win10`

Comment: Update your miktex.

Comment: My version is `Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3)`, is it old? Kindly suggest the recent version number...please...

Comment: the miktex version is not the point. The question is your version of the pdfmanagement. Current is `{pdfmanagement-testphase}{2022-03-17}{0.95m}`.