# Display math mode and the tooltip macro

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle, tooltips

I am using the tooltip macro defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers)

I realize that the following code works:

```latex
\tooltip****{foo}{\(x=4\)}
```

while

```latex
\tooltip****{foo}{\[x=4\]}
```

does not and it fails with

```
Bad math environment delimiter.
```

To me, the tooltip macro is like black magic but since it does not use any math stuff, I don't really understand where the error comes from. Is there a way to get around this?

In my case, the content of the tooltip comes from a variable and I would not mind *substituting*  `\[ \]` by `\( \)` when I use my variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\(`...`\)` produces inline math, while `\[` ... `\]`, being a shorthand for `\begin{displaymath}` ... `\end{displaymath}`, produces an unnumbered displayed equation. The latter cannot be typeset into an LR box (what the `\tooltip` tries to do). If you want a displayed equation to be typeset as a tooltip, wrap it into a `\parbox`:

```
\tooltip****{foo}{\parbox{1cm}{\[x=4\]}}
```

Other commands that make LR boxes: `\makebox`, `\framebox`, `\savebox`. Here, `\[` ... `\]` would fail with the same error message.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about LR boxes!