# How to make a pop up notice in adobe acrobat using LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, adobe, javascript

How to make a pop up notice in `adobe acrobat` using `LaTeX`? e.g. How can I simulate the left below corner pop up that shows page size by mouse hover.

[image]

Comment: well that pop-up is from the application. Beside this check the pdfcomment package.

Comment: Also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186