# Is it possible to make text in Overleaf like in Urban Dictionary where if you hover a word a window comes up with more information?

Tags: fancytooltips, tooltips

I'm trying to make text like in the Urban Dictionary like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in latex or some other text editor?

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips?lang=de

Comment: you have tagged it overleaf, but overleaf, or which editor you use makes no difference here the question is about tooltip features in PDF (less features than HTML ones that you show) and how to generate them in latex, but using a package as in the first comment will be the same whichever latex you use, not specific to overleaf (which uses texlive 2020)

Comment: Or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers