# How to make always visible the tooltip content on SumatraPDF?

Tags: tex-core, javascript, sumatrapdf

i am created a package for tooltip using [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers). Here my TeX code below

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[intlimits,tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{custom-tooltip}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{This is sample title}\label{chap:1}
This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. 



\begin{figure}[!t]
\tooltip{\includegraphics{LaTeX_cover.svg.png}}{This is LaTeX log.}[-150pt,-74pt]
\caption{This is LaTeX logo.}
\end{figure}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text.

\end{document}
```

And the `custom-tooltip.sty` was written

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/20]
\ProvidesPackage{custom-tooltip}[2020/11/30 custom-tooltip Package]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2019/09/26
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
%            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
%            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,linegoal}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\cListSet\clist_set:Nn\let\cListItem\clist_item:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}mO{0pt,0pt}%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    %\fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \tcbox[colframe=black,colback=#7,size=fbox,arc=0ex,
        sharp corners=southwest]{\parbox{0.70\textwidth}{\raggedright #8}}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \cListSet\tpOffsets{#9}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tipshift=12pt%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    %OCG-based (that is, all non-draggable) boxes should not extend beyond the
    %current column as they may get overlaid by text in the neighbouring column
    \setlength\whatsleft{\linegoal}%
  }{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  }%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\dimexpr\twd+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax%
    \setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd-\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp+\cListItem\tpOffsets{2}}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\dimexpr\tipshift+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
%\makeatother

\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

If i compile each time, i need to open this is in Adobe Reader to verify this content and placement in PDF. Where there was any possibility for showing the content always visible and also the placement in `SumatraPDF`. It was help me to save the time.

This tooltip was written in `JavaScript`. I don't have much knowledge in JavaScript. I manually changing `display.hidden` to `display.visible` and `this.dirty=false` to `this.dirty=true` and many more. All the method was not working for `SumatraPDF`

If i use `\tooltip**` content was viewed in `SumatraPDF` for 1st compile. If i compile 2nd time it was hidden and position was changed. There was any possible to use only `\tooltip` command and that tooltip will always visible on `SumatraPDF`?

Comment: Sumatra does not support Javascript.

Comment: Please see refer this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655635/how-to-create-framebox-in-tooltip-in-all-pdf-reader/674857#674857